# display:none and jquery show/slideDown

Tags: jquery, css

When using `display:none` in css:

```
#example {
display:none;
}
```

my content isn't showed with this jQuery function:

```
 $('#div1').on('mouseover', function() {
   $('#example').slideDown(2000);

   });
```

But when I use inline style argument `style="display:none"` it works.

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason behind this is CSS classes will be specifying the `display: none;` in the first case, but jQuery **thinks** the element is visible. To handle this, the best way to do is to define a class `.hidden`, which equates to `display: none;` and then assign the class to the `#example`.

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

Then, remove the class `hidden` from the element and hide it using jQuery on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hidden").hide().removeClass("hidden");
});
```

And after this, whatever you do using jQuery, works like charm.

---

#### Without CSS Classes

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#trigger").click(function () {
    $("#theDiv").toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#theDiv {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="trigger">Show / Hide</a>
<div id="theDiv">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

#### Using CSS `hidden` / jQuery Alternative

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".hidden").hide().removeClass("hidden");
  $("#trigger").click(function () {
    $("#theDiv").toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="trigger">Show / Hide</a>
<div id="theDiv" class="hidden">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this article about specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). That's what's groing wrong here. I am not quite sure what your exact structure/layout of your page is, but this is a clear case of where your CSS selector has less specificity than your inline style, so your inline style overrides the CSS style.

To fix this, you can see if there is another selector also defining the `display` style for this element, or if there is another inline style affecting this (probably mainly caused by JS then). If nothing else works, and **only** if nothing else works, you could use `display: none !important;` as your style in your CSS. But, like I said, **only** if **nothing** else works. Avoid `!important` whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery function .show() will accomplish you what you are looking for:

```
 $('#div1').on('mouseover', function() {
     $('#example').slideDown(2000);
     $('#example').show();
 });
```